# Unicorn error: "ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 12345 SIGABRT (signal 6)> worker=2"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

We get errors like this one daily (sometimes more than once):

```
Apr 13 12:16:31 app1 unicorn.log:  E, [2014-04-13T12:16:31.302011 #17269] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 17300 SIGABRT (signal 6)> worker=2
```

We use Unicorn 4.8.2 with a Ruby on Rails app.

It doesn't seem to happen at any obvious time, like during or just after deploys.

We're not sure how to debug this – any suggestions on either what the problem could be, or how to debug it?

Comment: Probably you're aware of it, but `SIGABRT` signal is usually called when there is a heap overflow, or other problems involving bad memory access. Frankly I don't know how to debug C, but in order to find out the culprit I would: 1) Update Ruby 2) Update Unicorn / Try another app server 3) Disable gems which include C extensions, and notice if the problem still raises

Comment: Thank you.  We did update Ruby and Unicorn. We were previously on Ruby 1.9.3 with Unicorn 4.8.0. Then we had almost the same issue but with SIGIOT, I believe. Then we upgraded Ruby to 2.1.1. I believe that's when it changed to SIGABRT. Then we upgraded Unicorn to 4.8.2 with no improvement. Disabling C gems is a good idea, though it might be a little tricky. Will look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was simply that our monit did a "kill -6" (SIBABRT) when the process
used too much memory, so we bumped that limit for now.

We've yet to research why it used that much memory.

Comment: Hi can you let me know how?

Comment: @KingsleyMitchell This was 10 years ago, so I don’t remember. Maybe post a new question?

Answer (score 0):

Remember to like :

This is the only way I have found: export RUBY_GC_HEAP_GROWTH_MAX_SLOTS=28000